# Custom dispatcher new CDT

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

I'm having compilation issues when creating a custom dispatcher. I'm getting issues when calling EOSIO_DISPATCH. Is it related to changes in new CDT?

```
class [[eosio::contract("mycontract")]] mycontract : public contract {
...
};

extern "C" {
void apply(uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action) {
    myContract thiscontract(name(receiver));

    if (((code == name("eosio.token").value) &&
        (action == name("transfer").value)) {
        execute_action(name(receiver), name(code) &myContract::transfer);
        return;
    }

    if (code != receiver) return;

      switch (action) { EOSIO_DISPATCH(myContract, (transfer)(receipt))
    }

    eosio_exit(0);
}
}
```

Errors and warnings I am getting:

```
warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function
  declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
mycontract thiscontract(name(receiver));
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
mycontract thiscontract(name(receiver));
                          ^
                          (             )
warning: 'thiscontract' has C-linkage specified, but
  returns user-defined type 'mycontract' which is incompatible with C
  [-Wreturn-type-c-linkage]
mycontract thiscontract(name(receiver));
             ^
error: call to non-static member function without an
  object argument
    execute_action(name(receiver), name(code) &mycontract::transfer);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
error: expected unqualified-id
  switch (action) { EOSIO_DISPATCH(mycontract, (transfer)(receipt)...
                    ^
```

/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/dispatcher.hpp:117:8: note: 
      expanded from macro 'EOSIO_DISPATCH'
extern "C" { \

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

1. As mentioned in the other post `myContract` should be lowercase `mycontract`.
2. The `eosio::contract` constructor changed since eosio.cdt 1.3. It takes 3 arguments now: `mycontract(eosio::name receiver, eosio::name code, eosio::datastream<const char *> ds) : contract(receiver, code, ds) {}`. Not sure if your `mycontract` already implements this as I can't see it from the code.
3. A custom dispatcher for `mycontract` could be written like this:

```
extern "C" {
void apply(uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action) {
  if (code == "eosio.token"_n.value && action == "transfer"_n.value) {
    eosio::execute_action(eosio::name(receiver), eosio::name(code),
                          &mycontract::transfer);
  } else if (code == receiver) {
    switch (action) { EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER(mycontract, (transfer)(receipt)) }
  }
  eosio_exit(0);
}
}
```

As a side note: You're allowing the `transfer` action to be called directly on your contract because you add it to `EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER` again. I'm not sure if that's intended. One could call it without doing an actual `eosio.token::transfer`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `EOSIO_DISPATCH` should be called `EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER`.
   Otherwise you are doing some kind of crazy recursive calling of the
   apply function.
2. There seems to be some confusion between `mycontract` and `myContract`.
3. You don't use `thiscontract` anywhere, so remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the other two posts and here is my complete code:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/action.hpp>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class [[eosio::contract("mycontract")]] mycontract: public eosio::contract {
  public:
    using contract::contract;

    [[eosio::action]]
    void transfer(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo) {
        /*if (to != _self) {
            return;
        }*/
        print("a transfer in mycontract:", name{ from }, ",", name{ to });
    }

};

extern "C" { 
    void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) { 
        if((code == "eosio.token"_n.value && action == "transfer"_n.value) ) { 

                eosio::execute_action(eosio::name(receiver), eosio::name(code), &mycintract::transfer);

           }else if(code == receiver){

                switch( action ) { 
                    EOSIO_DISPATCH_HELPER( mycontract, (transfer) ) 
                } 
            eosio_exit(0);
        } 

    } 
}
```

Here I only implement the `transfer` function, for an example. If you also need to add `receipt` function or other functions. You should do it like what `transfer` function do.
I hope it can be helpful.